# class in Fragment android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I got two fragment
This is fragment one

```
public class fragmentOne extends Fragment {

View view;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_process_hide, container, 

    return view;
}

}
```

And This is Fragment Two

```
public class fragmentTwo extends Fragment {

View view;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_process_hide, container, 

    return view;
}
}
public class data {
}
```

How can i access class data in fragment one from fragment two?
Thanks.

Comment: go through this link https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Comment: Thanks,Deliver a Message to a Fragment all it said , you know i'm trying to return something from a function in that class so i should call the class ,but I don't know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you cannot define two classes inside a file. So you should define the second class like this:

```
public class fragmentTwo extends Fragment {
    ...
    ...

    public class data {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

To access the class `data` from any other class other than `fragmentTwo`, class `data` should be *static*:

```
    ...
    public static class data {
        ...
    }
```

You can access `data` like this:

```
fragmentTwo.data data = ...
```

Hope this helps